# .ajax jquery not working with array size $_files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am at a complete loss with this one. I use this to submit images without refresh:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url:"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>",
        type:"POST",
        data:X,
        cache:false,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        beforeSend:function()
     });
```

but I have php verification to make sure there are only a limited number of images selected

```
if((sizeof($_FILES['IMAGE']) + $IMAGE_COUNT) > $POST_MAX_IMAGES)
```

For some reason, sizeof($_FILES['IMAGE'] is constantly stuck at 5??? I can't get a proper count of the number of files selected. Its always at 5. But if I do foreach on the $_FILES, it will go through all of them.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try checking the `max_file_uploads` setting in `php.ini`

Comment: ajax by itself does not support file upload... unless you are using `FormData`

Comment: Its at 20... this is weird because I can upload 25 images at once... but if I delete the images using ajax as well, going down to 20, I cannot upload back to 25 again. But I checked my $_FILES and its always return a value of 5

Comment: I use FormData, x is the FormData taken from that form

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to be

```
$_FILES['IMAGE']['name']
```

instead of

```
$_FILES['IMAGE']
```

Still curious about why, but it works